# How can I continue my proof of the continuity of a function defined by a dense collection of normally ascending open sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\o}{\mathcal{O}}$Let $\Lambda$ be a dense subset of $(a,b)\subset\Bbb R$, and $\{\o_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ a collection of open sets in some topological space $(X,\tau)$. I have to show that the function $f:X\to\Bbb R$ defined by:

$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}b&x\in X\setminus(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\o_\lambda)\\\inf\{\lambda:x\in\o_\lambda\}&x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\o_\lambda\end{cases}$$

Is continuous when $\o_\lambda$ is a normally ascending family. Royden defines normally ascending like this:

$$\lambda_2\gt\lambda_1\implies\o_{\lambda_2}\supseteq\overline{\o_{\lambda_1}}$$

The fact that it is continuous is strongly obvious to me, which is why the paper author left it as an exercise, but actually showing it rigorously is proving to be difficult; I have become lost in the topological details.

I need to show that:

> $\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\forall x\in X,\,\exists N(x)\in\tau$ a neighbourhood in which $y\in N(x)\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\lt\varepsilon$.

I think I have shown that the density of $\Lambda$ implies I can always choose two $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ arbitrarily close:

> Density in $(a,b)$ means $\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\forall r\in(a,b)\setminus\Lambda,\,\exists\lambda\in\Lambda:|r-\lambda|\lt\varepsilon$. $\lambda\in\Lambda\implies\lambda\in(a,b)\implies\exists(\lambda-\delta,\lambda+\delta)\subset(a,b)$, and choosing any $r\in(\lambda-\delta/2,\lambda+\delta/2)$ one can find $\lambda'\in\Lambda:|\lambda'-r|\lt\delta/2$ i.e. $|\lambda-\lambda'|\lt\delta$ for any sufficiently small $\delta\gt0$.

I also assume $\Lambda$ is a countable set, since as far as I know uncountable union has little meaning; $f$ is immediately continuous outside of the union of $\o$, and inside the union we have, by normal ascension, that the closure of $\o_{\lambda_1}$ is a subset of $\o_{\lambda_2}$ if $\lambda_2\gt\lambda_1$. At first I thought that that meant I could simply assume strict subsets, but then I realised that we do have clopen sets, so the closure of $\o$ may well be $\o$ itself for some $\o_\lambda$. This is a problem, since any $y$ in a neighbourhood of $x$ could be in an indeterminate number of smaller $\o_\lambda$, so it is not clear how to set up an inequality.

My original plan was to use the fact that if $x\in\o_\lambda$, $f(x)\le\lambda$, and then find a way to select a sufficiently small neighbourhood in which $y\notin\o_{\lambda'}$, for some $\lambda'\lt\lambda$, and then use the density to make $\lambda-\lambda'\lt\varepsilon$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon$. My difficulty is perhaps in my understanding of what a normally ascending collection looks like; as soon as I remembered that clopen sets are a thing, and that any $x\in\o_\lambda$ may well be a limit point of potentially *all* the $\o$, the act of choosing a sufficiently small neighbourhood went from intuitively immediate to ... seemingly impossible. There is an added complication that the infimum will always exist in $(a,b)$, but won't always exist in $\Lambda$, although I'm sure I can use the density again to salvage that.

If anyone could offer insight on how to salvage my plan I'd greatly appreciate it. If my plan cannot be salvaged, I'd like a hint on how to proceed. It frustrates me that I am struggling to prove the obvious! Maybe my intuition is wrong and it isn't as obvious as I thought.

Comment: Maybe consider the equivalent condition of continuous map is easier? -- For all open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R},$ $f^{-1}(U)$ is a open set in $X$. It's equivalent to prove the case when $U$ is an open interval. Also equivalent to prove when $U=(\alpha,\beta),$ $\forall \alpha<\beta\in \Lambda$

Comment: @DreamAR Maybe, I’ll give it a go. Is it equivalent since any open set in $\Bbb R$ is expressive as a countable disjoint union of intervals? I’m curious; in higher dimensions, I can say the same (just losing the disjointness): is it equivalent there too?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is from Royden’s real analysis and I assumed the term was standard; I’ll edit in the definition

Comment: @FShrike As $f^{-1}(\bigcup_\lambda U_\lambda)=\bigcup_\lambda f^{-1}(U_\lambda),$ and open sets are closed under union operation, you can just take any topological basis. As $f^{-1}(\bigcap_\lambda U_\lambda)=\bigcap_\lambda f^{-1}(U_\lambda),$ you can also consider topology subbasis only. By the way, in this way the proof can be done. I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equivalent to prove that $f^{-1}((\alpha,\beta))$ is an open set in $X$, $\forall \alpha<\beta\in \mathbb{R}.$ That means $\forall x$ with $f(x)\in (\alpha,\beta),$ find an open set $U\ni x$ such that $f(U)\subset (\alpha,\beta)$ when $f^{-1}((\alpha,\beta))\neq \varnothing.$ First prove the case when $(\alpha,\beta)\subset (a,b).$ I think we only need to add some details when $\alpha<a$ or $\beta> b$.

Take $l\in \Lambda,$ satisfied that $\alpha<l<f(x),$ show that $x\notin\overline{\mathcal{O}}_l.$ Find $r\in \Lambda,$ satisfied that $f(x)<r<\beta,$ and $x\in \mathcal{O}_r.$ Now take $U=\mathcal{O}_r\setminus\overline{\mathcal{O}}_l,$ the job is done.

Comment: You can take $l$ arbitary, while $r$ needs to be choosed.

Comment: chosen, not choosed.

Comment: My issue always was with actually fixing a lower bound $l$; in my question I explain why that is. Using your strategy, I arrive at $x\in\mathcal{O}_r\setminus\mathcal{O}_l$, but this set difference *could* be empty, as far as I can see

Comment: @FShrike Empty set is open, so it also works. And you need to show $x\in \mathcal{O}_r\setminus \overline{\mathcal{O}}_l,$ to have an open set.

Comment: I have satisfied myself that $$f^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda\\\alpha\lt\lambda\lt\beta}\mathcal{O}_\lambda$$Which is open. Is this right?

Comment: @FShrike Yes I think it's right.

Comment: Yes I see your edit. Thank you! This perspective is simpler; + welcome new contributor, and thank you for contributing