# A more straightforward proof of "Urysohn's Lemma" (Theorem 2.12) as it is presented in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Rudin states Urysohn's Lemma as follows:

$\textbf{Theorem Statement}$

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $V$ is open in $X$, $K\subset V$, and $K$ is compact. Then there exists an $f\in C_c(X)$ such that
$$
K\prec f\prec V.
$$
Here, $K\prec f$ means $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, that $f\in C_c(X)$, that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in X$, and that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in K$.

Similarly, $f\prec V$ means $V$ is open, $f\in C_c(X)$, $0\leq f\leq1$, and that the support of $f$ lies in $V$.

$\textbf{Rudin's Proof}$

Rudin constructs an open set $V_r$ with compact closure for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, such that $K\subset V_1,\ \overline{V_0}\subset V$, each $\overline{V_r}$ is compact, and such that
$$
s>r\enspace\textrm{implies}\enspace\overline{V_s}\subset V_r.
$$

He then defines
$$
f_r(x)=
\begin{cases}
r&\textrm{if}\enspace x\in V_r, \\
0&\textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\qquad g_s(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&\textrm{if}\enspace x\in\overline{V_s}, \\
s&\textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
as well as
$$
f=\sup\limits_r f_r,\qquad g=\inf\limits_s g_s.
$$

He notes lower semicontinuity of $f$ and upper semicontinuity of $g$ and then proves that $f=g$ to show $f$ is continuous.

$\textbf{My Question(s)}$

Why does Rudin choose his method of proof? My proof below is just as well suited to introduce the concept of semicontinuity as Rudin's proof; isn't it much more straightforward to define
$$
f_r(x)=
\begin{cases}
r&\textrm{if}\enspace x\in\overline{V_r}, \\
0&\textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
and to set $f=\sup\limits_r f_r$? We may directly prove $f$ is continuous as follows:

$\textbf{My Proof}$

Define $f,f_r$ as they are defined in section immediately above (My Question(s)). First, note that for any $q\in[0,1)$ we have
$$
f^{-1}(q,\infty)=\bigcup_{r>q}\overline{V_r}=\bigcup_{r>q}V_r.
$$

On the other hand, $f^{-1}(1,\infty)=\varnothing$.

Second, observe that any rational $r\in(0,1]$ satisfies
$$
f^{-1}(-\infty,r)=(\overline{V_r})^c.
$$
On the other hand, $f^{-1}(-\infty,0)=\varnothing$.

Hence any open interval of the form $(q,r)$ where $q,r\in[0,1]$, $q<r$, and $r$ is rational satisfies the condition that $f^{-1}((q,r))$ is open. It follows from this and the above comments that $f^{-1}(W)$ is open for any open $W\subset\mathbb{R}$, i.e., that $f$ is continuous, since any open interval $(a,b)\subset[0,1]$ may be written as a union of intervals of the form $(q,r)$, where $r$ is rational, and $a\leq q<r\leq b$.

It is easy to see that my $f$ satisfies the conditions that $0\leq f\leq1$, that $f(x)=1$ if $x\in K$, and that $f$ has support in $\overline{V_0}$, just as Rudin's $f$ does.

Comment: What is $f$ in your proof? The statement of Urysohn’s lemma doesn’t explicitly define $f$.

Comment: @Divide1918 I put it in the post but I apologize if the post is a bit lengthy and the details too obscured, I defined $f=\sup\limits_rf_r$ where $f_r$ is as defined in the section entitled "My Question". I fixed the wording to make it more clear what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your proof but your idea is exactly what is done in Royden and Fitzpatrick's proof of this result, at least in the 4th edition of their textbook "Real Analysis". Specifically, it is left as an [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4305824) to show that:

> If $(X,\tau)$ is any topological space, $a<b$ two real numbers, $\Lambda\subseteq(a,b)$ any dense subset and $\mathcal{O}_\bullet:\Lambda\to\tau$ any normally ascending family of open sets, meaning that if $\lambda<\lambda'$ we have $\overline{\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_{\lambda'}$, then the Urysohn function: $$f:X\to\Bbb R,\,x\mapsto\begin{cases}b&x\notin\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mathcal{O}_\lambda\\\inf\{\lambda\in\Lambda:x\in\mathcal{O}_\lambda\}&x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mathcal{O}_\lambda\end{cases}$$Is continuous with image contained in $[a,b]$.

Up to a reindexing (mine is normally *as*cending, yours normally *de*scending) you can see that this construction is just a slight generalisation of your suggestion, and probably simpler than whatever Rudin did in his text.

Comment: Great response, thank you. I suppose Rudin's proof isn't that complicated but it seems strange introducing two definitions of a function when it is quite easy to use one and prove continuity directly. I will check out the Royden Fitzpatrick text and use it as a supplement; I really love Rudin's book and the way he approaches most topics but it wouldn't hurt to have another good source for real analysis material.